# Can I access iCloud/device data of the hacker who logged into my account?

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id

I noticed someone else has been using my iCloud but it doesn’t show up under “my devices”

Since they are logged into my iCloud and can receive my Messages/FaceTime etc, is there anyway I can access there information since there connected to my iCloud?

Comment: Why don't you just change your iCloud password?

Comment: It is just out of curiosity...like if there able to see my stuff, are we able to see theres?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no in the sense that you cannot get access to data only stored on their device, or data stored in their iCloud account.

Any data they choose to store in your own iCloud account, you can ofcourse see. I.e. if they for example add a photo to your photo library, it will show up in your Photos app.

I would advise immediately changing the password and security questions on the account, and then enable 2-factor authentication using the following guide:

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204915

Comment: To add: Do this as a matter of urgency. To illustrate what *may* happen, please read [Matt Honan's article in Wired from 2012](https://www.wired.com/2012/08/apple-amazon-mat-honan-hacking/). Ok, so an attacker exploited errors in Apple's infra that may or may not exist any more, but the central message is the same. Don't delay! Interesting article.